# Proof explanation of a simple sum

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, proof-explanation

Can someone explain to me (step by step), how the following summation goes from the left to the right:

$\sum_{i=1}^{r}n(1-p)^{i-1} = n(1-(1-p)^r)/p$.

I'm having trouble with maths..

Comment: This is a simple geometric sum.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

You can proof by induction that $$\sum_{i=0}^np^i=\frac{1-p^{n+1}}{1-p},$$ or just observe by simple calculation that $$(1-p)\sum_{i=0}^np^i=(1-p)(1+p+p^2+\cdots +p^n)=1-p^{n+1}.$$

Comment: @GoldenRetriever: it does make sense, if you spend the effort of changing the variables.

Comment: It makes more sense after reading up on partial sums for geometric series. I have done this: $(1-p)\sum_{i=0}^{r}n^{i-1}$ and come to the solution: $S_n=n*\frac{1-(1-p^r)}{1-(1-p)}$. From here, how do I get to: $\frac{n(1-(1-p)^r)}{p}$ ??

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{r}n(1-p)^{i-1}+n(1-p)^r = n+\sum_{i=2}^{r+1}n(1-p)^{i-1}= n+(1-p)\sum_{i=1}^{r}n(1-p)^{i-1}.$$

You can draw $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{r}n(1-p)^{i-1}$ from this.

Comment: @GoldenRetriever: the usual arithmetic rules in a ring.